# Make images fit inside a card without altering the size of said card (bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a boostrap 5 card split into 2 columns.

| First COlumn | Second column |
| --- | --- |
| Image1 | Text |
| Image2 | Text |

The problem is that obvioulsy not all image have the same size, which also impacted the size of the cards.

I found a way (on this forum actually) to make the cards all the same size. But I am struggling to make the actual image fit in its respective column. (see image below)

Is there a way to simply make the image fit the div it is in for both height and width, without altering the size of the card?

[image]

Code wise, this is what I have:
**template**

```
{% extends 'main/base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<h1 class="b1">Venues</h1>
<br/>
{% for venue in venue_list%}
<a href="{% url 'show-venue' venue.id%}"> <div class="row mt-2 mb-3 card-horizontal">
    <div class="col-6 mt-2 mb-3 ">
    <img class="card-img-top border-card card-img"  src='{{venue.venue_image}}'>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 mt-2 mb-3">
    <h4 class="b5">Logo</h4>
    </div>

  </div></a>
{%endfor%}
```

**css**

```
.card-img-top {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20wv;
        object-fit: cover;
    }


    .card-horizontal {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 158px 22px;
        background-color: #090B1A! important;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #B3D4DB;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, in the css I replaced `object-fit: cover` by `object-fit: contain`.

```
.card-img-top {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25vw;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
```

This had for result to resize the images based on the size allocated to them by the parent card.